# Stringbuilder to check for a string but skip that String and return other Strings

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuilder

Stringbuilder to search for a particular string but skip that string and return all other string appended.

It currently returns all the strings.

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
while(!group.isEof()){
    groupname= group.getFieldValueString(USER_GROUP);
    sb.append(";"+groupname);
    group.moveNext();
}
printOut(USER+sb.toString());
```

Input (ABC;XYZ;RTY) or (ERT;ABC;XYZ;RTY)
If String contains ABC then only display (XYZ;RTY) in 1st example,(ERT;XYZ;RTY) in 2nd example

Comment: This seems it might be the wrong approach. Assuming Java, why not accumulate the list of strings in an `ArrayList` or similar and then remove 'ABC' from the list, then use `USER+String.join(";", mylist)` to build up the list. Please tag with Java or .NET depending on which `StringBuilder` you are referring to.

Comment: what are group, isEof, groupname, printOut, USER, USER_GROUP? Please, provide a compilable snippet...

Comment: Why can't you use `if (groupname.equals(...))` ?

Comment: Its our internal tool's syntax but groupname is in string format.So i just want to skip 1 particular string from all the groups appended in the string builder sb.

Comment: Thanks rghome however there is one issue i noticed, it still displays that row. I would completely want to skip that record.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is to append all the strings you want then use the String replace method.

```
String str = sb.toString().replace("ABC;","");
printOut(USER+str);
```

Note: replace method will replace **all** substrings that are equal to the first argument with the second argument which is in this case is empty.

You can modify this approach to suit your needs.